# Move null value down to next row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have this table

```
call_date    cust_code  order_id
   2020-06-20   A001       s001 
   2020-06-21   A001       s002 
   2020-06-22   A001       NULL 
   2020-06-23   A001       s003 
   2020-06-24   A001       s004 
   2020-06-25   A001       NULL 
   2020-06-26   A001       s005
```

and I want to first check next 3 records if any record from three not null, then swap null value with the next value of null and vice-versa like this:

```
   call_date    cust_code  order_id
   2020-06-20   A001       s001 
   2020-06-21   A001       s002 
   2020-06-22   A001       s003
   2020-06-23   A001       s004 
   2020-06-24   A001       s005 
   2020-06-25   A001       NULL 
   2020-06-26   A001       NULL
```

I did this

```
update effective set order_id=ISNULL(order_id,(select Top 1 e2.order_id 
from effective e2 where e2.call_date>e1.call_date
AND e2.order_id IS NOT NULL)
) 
FROM effective e1
```

and got this:

```
call_date    cust_code  order_id
   2020-06-20   A001       s001 
   2020-06-21   A001       s002 
   2020-06-22   A001       s003 
   2020-06-23   A001       s003 
   2020-06-24   A001       s004 
   2020-06-25   A001       s005
   2020-06-26   A001       s005
```

Can someone assist me and solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Either I understand the issue qrong or there might be quite easy workaround. I just created the following querym ehich uses ctes to get all orders on the one hand and all orders with a set order_id on the other hand. Next I perform a left join between both ctes - and the resukt looks like what you tried to achieve...

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
call_date date,
cust_code nvarchar(10),
order_id nvarchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('2020-06-20', 'A001', 's001'), 
('2020-06-21', 'A001', 's002'), 
('2020-06-22', 'A001', NULL), 
('2020-06-23', 'A001', 's003'), 
('2020-06-24', 'A001', 's004'), 
('2020-06-25', 'A001', NULL), 
('2020-06-26', 'A001', 's005');

WITH cteBase AS(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_code ORDER BY call_date) rn
  FROM @t t
),
cteNotNULL AS(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_code ORDER BY call_date) rn
  FROM @t t
  WHERE order_id IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT b.call_date, b.cust_code, n.order_id
  FROM cteBase b
  LEFT JOIN cteNotNULL n ON n.cust_code = b.cust_code AND n.rn = b.rn
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If the solution works for you, I would appreciate if you accept the answer.

Comment: sir your answer don't match a condition . sir i want to swap value with null after chacking condition if i get null value in order_id then it will check for next 3 date in order id column for not null value if just next is null then it will check next then that value should be swap up with null.